# Dev tools: keep hover state on reload

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

It's pretty cumbersome to work with drop down menus, mega menus if hover state is required all the time to display drop down, and once you reload the page, you have to pick a mouse and set hover state on the element again.

The questions is - how to keep the hover state on the element even if the page is reloaded, so I don't have do it again? Possible?

Comment: I feel you man. However, what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the title was not good enough for that. The questions is - how to keep the hover state on the element even if the page is reloaded, so I don't have do it again? Possible?